# How To Work On Specific 2d Plane While In Perspective Mode?

Tags: edit-mode, workflow, orthographic

To work on either XY , YZ or XZ plane, I have to go to ortho view left/top/front. But if I'm in perspective mode, how can I activate selected plane to work on while still in perspective?

To clarify maybe something like modo's construction plane or work plane:
https://youtu.be/1Ms0v0VsJhY?t=95

Where we can see and predict the location in 3d space (while drawing in perspective). The construction plane will adapt or orient itself when we rotate the view to choose the closest 'correct' plane.

---

Is there something like this in blender? Currently, while in perspective, I have to constantly press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> , <kbd>Y</kbd> ,<kbd>Z</kbd> to constrain the direction of the movement.

Comment: these could be find usually in cad programs like freecad... though I once reproduce that with making a plane and turn on snap to surface and I would enable disable it using outliner
Edit, maybe a cad plugin would have that? I would love to know if you find the answer.